# Host information from a crash dump file

Tags: windbg, sos

Is it possible to get information about the host where a dump file was been created e.g., OS version, service pack, .NET framework version etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS version and so forth is listed automatically when you open the dump file.

You can get the .NET framework version using the `!eeversion` command.

```
0:000> !eeversion
2.0.50727.4952 free
Workstation mode
SOS Version: 2.0.50727.4952 retail build
```

To get additional information for loaded modules use the verbose option for `lm`. E.g.

```
0:000> lm vm mscoree
start             end                 module name
000007fe`f0f10000 000007fe`f0f7f000   mscoree    (deferred)             
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll
    Image name: mscoree.dll
    Timestamp:        Fri Nov 06 06:09:26 2009 (4AF3AF86)
    CheckSum:         00072187
    ImageSize:        0006F000
    File version:     4.0.31106.0
    Product version:  4.0.31106.0
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® .NET Framework
    InternalName:     mscoree.dll
    OriginalFilename: mscoree.dll
    ProductVersion:   4.0.31106.0
    FileVersion:      4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
    PrivateBuild:     DDBLD278
    FileDescription:  Microsoft .NET Runtime Execution Engine
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    Comments:         Flavor=Retail
```

Answer (score 1):

Also the `vertarget` command displays current version of the Microsoft Windows operating. system