# How to detect platform from dump using Windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg

I have a dump and I want to know using Windbg from what platform it is (Win32 or X64).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4173312/38206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's what the `.effmach` command does.